# ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, case

My table has these columns:

```
|blo|NotionalCurrency|Notional|Premiumcurrency|Basecurrency|Termcurrency|StructureName|Basemarketprice|Termmarketpriceprecent |Termmarketprice|
```

I want to get blo, currency and price from these. Below is my SQL:

```
   select blo.opt,
  case
  when opt.premiumcurrency is not null and opt.structurename is not null  then currency = opt.premiumcurrency
      case
      when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency then price = opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
      else
          case
             when opt.premiumcurrency = opt.basecurrency then price = opt.basemarketprice /100
             else
             price = opt.termmarketpriceprecent /100
             end
       end
   when price = 0 then price = 0.000001
   end
FROM interface opt
WHERE opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency;
```

But I get error: `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

**Basically, the logic below should be used to get/derive SQL to get three columns: Blo, currency and price:**

```
If notional currency = base currency and premium currency=term currency Then
               Price =term market price/notional
               currency = notional currency
Else
               If notional currency = premium currency then
                              Price= base market price /100
                              currency = termcurrency
               else
                              Price=term market price percent /100
                              currency = notional
               end if
end if
if price=0 then 
price=0.000001
end if
```

Comment: There's a comma missing after `blo.opt`

Comment: The second case follows the first, without an else/case condition. Also I think you have too many nested case for no reason, please [edit] and post what exactly your requirements are

Comment: Editing your question in a way that invalidates an existing answer seems kind of rude. Someone coming to this question now will think Bonesist's answer is irrelevant or wrong unless they check the edit history.

Comment: @Alex. Apologies. I did not want to raise another questions that is why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems here. Breaking it down a bit:

```
  case
  when opt.premiumcurrency is not null
    and opt.structurename is not null
```

From the `where` condition, `opt.premiumcurrency` cannot be null so that check isn't adding anything.

```
  then currency = opt.premiumcurrency
```

You can't set a value here; it looks like you want this to be an expression that is labelled as `currency` in the final output, as Arka showed.

```
      case
      when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
        and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency
      then price = opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
```

Now you're looking for price, not currency, so this isn't part of the previous case clause; which means you should have had an `end as currency,` by now. But you also don't have an `else` condition, meaning your currency expression will be null if `opt.structurename` is null; not clear if that is what you want.

But again both of these conditions must be true because of your `where` clause, making this whole `case` redundant. And again you want an expression alias, not to try to set a value with `=`.

```
      else
          case
             when opt.premiumcurrency = opt.basecurrency
             then price = opt.basemarketprice /100
             else
             price = opt.termmarketpriceprecent /100
          end
       end
```

You've nested a case here so it looks like you're trying to convert an if/elsif/else construct directly, without considering how the semantics of [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm) actually work. The nested case/end isn't needed as this when/end can be part of the enclosing case. But as noted above, the first `when` condition always has to be true, and `opt.premiumcurrency = opt.basecurrency` also always has to be true, so all of this is redundant too.

```
   when price = 0 then price = 0.000001
```

This is just floating there, so this needs to be an outer case or decode, or possibly a `least()` if the value can never be negative.

So with the `where` conditions you showed, this can be reduced to:

```
select opt.blo,
  case
    when opt.structurename is not null then opt.premiumcurrency
  end as currency,
  case
    when opt.termmarketpricepercent = 0 then 0.000001
    else opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
  end as price
from interface opt
where opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency;
```

If the `where` clause is temporary and you need a more general query then it's still simpler than you were making it:

```
select opt.blo,
  case
    when opt.premiumcurrency is not null
      and opt.structurename is not null 
        then opt.premiumcurrency
    end as currency, -- still no 'else' so null if structurename is null
    decode (
      case
        when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
          and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency
          then opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
        when opt.premiumcurrency = opt.basecurrency
          then opt.basemarketprice /100
        else opt.termmarketpricepercent /100
      end, 0, 0.000001) as price
from interface opt;
```

(I've swapped `blo.opt` to `opt.blo` as Sathya spotted, and also fixed a typo in at least one column reference...)

Based on your latest edit, you want the currency and price to both be picked based on the same conditions, which wasn't obvious from the original query. Each case can only evaluate to one value, so you need to repeat the conditions in two expressions, one for currency and one for price; and then you still want to change the price if it is zero. Again assuming the `where` is temporary:

```
select opt.blo,
  case
    when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
      and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency
      then opt.notionalcurrency
    when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.premiumcurrency
      then opt.termcurrency
    else opt.notionalcurrency
  end as currency,
  decode (
    case
      when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
        and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency
        then opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
      when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.premiumcurrency
        then opt.basemarketprice / 100
      else opt.termmarketpricepercent / 100
    end, 0, 0.000001) as price
from interface opt;
```

The price calculation is the same as before, the currency expression has changed to match the same logic. You seem to have lost the `structurename` check now though. And there's an underlying assumption that none of the currency values are null, really.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b4bb/2) with partial table and no data, just to show the queries don't error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code returns results. I will get back asap as the requirements seem to have changed a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the `end` from the initial case statement. Simply add it after the `when price = 0 then price = 0.000001`

Comment: Thanks. I added it now I get `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Comment: @Sathya has already provided you the reason why you're now getting the missing keyword error. He raises some excellent points in his comments and answer!

Comment: @ALL, I have updated what the logic should be for me to get the required 3 columns I need. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT opt.blo,
       CASE
         WHEN (opt.premiumcurrency IS NOT NULL
           AND opt.structurename IS NOT NULL) THEN
           currency = opt.premiumcurrency
       END,
       CASE
         WHEN (opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
           AND opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency) THEN
           price = opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
         WHEN price = 0 THEN
           price = 0.000001
         WHEN opt.premiumcurrency = opt.basecurrency THEN
           price = opt.basemarketprice / 100
         ELSE
           price = opt.termmarketpriceprecent / 100
       END
  FROM interface opt
 WHERE opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency
   AND opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have several things about this query:

1. As per my understanding opt is the alias name of your table and to get attribute you should write opt.blo not blo.opt.
2. Case statement should contain case value, like the column name where you are using the case statement

I have tried to modify the code. Not compiled so there may be syntax error. Just check it.

```
  select opt.blo,
  case opt.currency
  when opt.premiumcurrency is not null and opt.structurename is not null
  then opt.premiumcurrency
  end as Currency,
  case opt.price
  when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency then opt.termmarketpricepercent / opt.notional
  when opt.premiumcurrency = opt.basecurrency then opt.basemarketprice /100
  when price = 0 then price = 0.000001
  else
  opt.termmarketpriceprecent /100
  end as Price,
FROM interface opt
WHERE opt.notionalcurrency = opt.basecurrency and opt.premiumcurrency = opt.termcurrency;
```

Comment: Thanks. I run your code but I still get `ORA-00905`

Comment: `case opt.currency` is invalid syntax if you also try to specify the column in the `when opt.premiumcurrency ...` condition.

Comment: @Alex i haven't used the column name any where in the when condition

Comment: @ALL, I have updated what the logic should be for me to get the required 3 columns I need. thanks in advance.

Comment: @ArkaBanerjee - you're mixing [simple and searched case expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm). There isn't a plain `opt.currency` column anyway, and as two things are being tested it can't be a simple case; it should just be `case when opt.premiumcurrency is not null ...` as a searched case?

Comment: @Alex  thanks about correction and also for the topic simple and searched case expression syntax...